# How to fix "} expected" when trying to create an enum in a console application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an enum in c# using a visual studio console application, yet the opening curly bracket of my Main method gives an error saying that I need a closing curly bracket.

I've tried copying and pasting the code for the enum into a windows forms application, and I don't get an error there.

```cs
using System;

namespace autoDagwaarde
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            enum BrandstofSoort { bezine, diesel };
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this to work, since I use the right amount of opening and closing curly brackets, but instead I get an error right below "static void Main", "} expected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` should be defined inside a namespace, not inside a method.
Define your `enum` outside the main function:

```cs
using System;

namespace autoDagwaarde
{
    class Program
    {
        enum BrandstofSoort { bezine, diesel };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Also note it's called an [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) and not an enumerator which is something else in C#!

Answer (score 0):

A enum is a class itself, so to define it you need to do is outside the Main.
Would be here:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
    {
        enum BrandstofSoort
        {
            bezine,
            diesel
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Or here:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    enum BrandstofSoort
    {
        bezine,
        diesel
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It can be also the namespace so the class would be in the globalnamespace.
Then you can use an instance of your defined class in the main.
Hope that helps

Answer (score -3):

```
using System;

namespace autoDagwaarde
{
    class Program
    {
        enum BrandstofSoort { bezine, diesel };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // write your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't only post code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.